# How to eliminate the collision of two circles?

Tags: geometry

I have two circles with the same radius that intersect each other, I need to move one of them to some X and Y values so that they intersect only at one point (so that they do not lie on each other anymore).
How to calculate X and Y, which need to move one of the circles?

Comment: let say circle A is at coordinates (x,y), since they have the same radius, you have to make sure that ((xa - xb)^2 + (ya - yb)^2) ^ (1/2) = 2r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to move each circle away from the other when an overlap is detected:

*While the distance between the two centers is less than the sum of the two radii, move each circle a little bit away from the other*.

```
# r0, r1, epsilon, Scalars representing radii and a small value
# c0, c1, center Points
# ((c1 - c0) / |c1 - c0|) normalized c0c1 vector away from c1
# ((c0 - c1) / |c1 - c0|) normalized c0c1 vector away from c0


while (r0 + r1) > |c1 - c0|:
    c0 = c0 + ((c1 - c0) / |c1 - c0|) * epsilon
    c1 = c1 + ((c0 - c1) / |c1 - c0|) * epsilon
```

**Edit**: Example class Point (python) for convenient arithmetic:

```
class point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __sub__(self, other) -> Vector:
         return Vector(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)
    ...
```

Comment: No, as indicated in the comments header in the code, center points are Point objects: you must create objects representing a `Point`, that you can subtract to obtain a `Vector`, add to a `Vector` to obtain a new `point`, and perform usual arithmetic on Points and Vectors.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
float r // = radius
float A[2] //= coordinates of the center A of the first circle
float B[2] //= coordinates of the center B of the second circle
float AB[2];
float length_AB;
float B_new[2];


AB[0] = B[0] - A[0];
AB[1] = B[1] - A[1];

length_AB = math.sqrt( AB[0]*AB[0] + AB[1]*AB[1] );

AB[0] = 2 * r * AB[0] / length_AB;
AB[1] = 2 * r * AB[1] / length_AB;

B_new[0] = A[0] + AB[0];
B_new[1] = A[1] + AB[1];
```